# Circular dependency error in will_paginate when try install geocode geolite database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, activerecord

I get error in:
   rails 4.1
   ruby 2.1
   will_paginate 3.0
   activerecord 4.2

Any idea? Thanks!

```
rake geocoder:maxmind:geolite:load PACKAGE=city
File already exists (GeoLiteCity_20151201/GeoLiteCity-Blocks.csv), skipping
File already exists (GeoLiteCity_20151201/GeoLiteCity-Location.csv), skipping
Resetting table maxmind_geolite_city_blocks...rake aborted!
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ActiveRecord
/***lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:247:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/***lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:23:in `<module:WillPaginate>'
/***lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/geocoder-1.2.11/lib/maxmind_database.rb:26:in `block in insert'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/geocoder-1.2.11/lib/maxmind_database.rb:24:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/geocoder-1.2.11/lib/maxmind_database.rb:24:in `insert'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/geocoder-1.2.11/lib/tasks/maxmind.rake:71:in `insert!'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/geocoder-1.2.11/lib/tasks/maxmind.rake:25:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => geocoder:maxmind:geolite:load => geocoder:maxmind:geolite:insert
```

Comment: could you add more info w.r.t. code

Comment: is the fine in your project or outside `/***lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb`?

Comment: Hola, Vinay, majlb. Es todo codigo de entrada y salida. El / *** es el reemplazo de mi ruta del proyecto, como por ejemplo / home / user / proyecto. Así que no hay ningún problema con la ruta. ¡Gracias!